# Phone Tracker, How does this work, and could it be used?

Tags: data-request

So I found a website: [Phone Report](http://phone.report/) and the peculiar thing about it is that it provides a activity map of where that phone has been. I quickly tried to dig through the website's source and network activity, and found it was loading a Open Street Map Layer. I'm wondering if the common GPS locations of a phone number could be extracted from that. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Open Street Map, Most of my time has been spent in World Wind. Could anyone look into this as a possible data source?

[image: Activity Map]

Comment: whatever you are doing....respect user privacy first and foremost.